# How to grab innerHTML from DOMNode

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I'm attempting to replace all `<foo>` elements in a DOMDocument with `<bar>` elements. The best way to do this seems to be to grab all the `<foo>` elements with getElementsByTagName and then create new elements to replace these with.

The problem is, I can't see to grab the innerHTML from the element which is being replaced. nodeValue and textContent both return the inner text, but the inner tags get stripped away. How can a I get something similar to "innerHTML" from a DOMElement?

Sample code:

```
function convertTags($doc, $type) {

$bad_nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName($type); 

foreach($bad_nodes as $bad_node) {
    $good_node = $doc->createElement("bar", $bad_node->nodeValue);
    $bad_node->parentNode->replaceChild($good_node, $bad_node); 
}

return $doc;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just `str_replace('<foo','<bar',$text)`?

Comment: @Kongr45pen: because that would practically mean parsing HTML with a regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could do better by treating them like actual nodes:

```
$good_node = $doc->createElement('bar');
foreach( $bad_node->childNodes as $kid )
{
    $good_node->appendChild( $kid );
}
```

Comment: +1 this. Anyways, if it _has_ to be a string, replace the `appendNode` call with something like `$string .= $doc->saveHTML($kid);`

Comment: This seems to work in theory, but ends up not actually appending all of $bad_node's children. It seems that when the first child node is appended, somehow the chain to the rest of the subchildren is broken. Thus $good_node only gets one (empty) node appended to it, even when there are many subnodes.

Comment: I +1'd this, but upon closer inspection, what is `appendNode()`? Is it supposed to be `appendChild()` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php)?

Comment: Well, fair enough. Misrememberized it, I guess.

Comment: Going by the docs, after creating `$good_node` with `createElement()`, you'd need to insert it into the DOM tree somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`DOMDocument::saveHTML()`](http://us.php.net/manual/domdocument.savehtml.php) method, and specify the node you want to dump.  If I understand which of the nodes in your example you're looking to extract the HTML from, try something like:

```
foreach($bad_nodes as $bad_node) {
    $good_node = $doc->createElement("bar", $bad_node->nodeValue);
    $bad_node->parentNode->replaceChild($good_node, $bad_node); 

    // Call saveHTML on the node you want to dump.
    $doc->saveHTML($bad_node);

}
```

Comment: Didn't change what ended up being returned - all of the right text, but with all of the tags stripped away. I feel like it has something to do with the $doc->createElement("bar", THIS_METHOD_RIGHT_HERE) which is not actually returning the HTML w/ tags, etc - just the inner values.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you move all the child nodes of your bad element into your good element instead?  Can this not be done without using an innerHTML type method?

I believe saveHTML() should return the markup of the node you apply it to, if that's any help to you.